# Creating Calendar with multi-date selector in Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am developing Multi date selector calendar using Angular 2 and ionic 2 for my app.

I wanted to know how to get all the dates in specific month .
Example in Angular 2
If i select Jan 2017 from Month-picker . Method should return arrays of date from 01/01/2017 to 31/01/2017

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Please try this plugin

It can provide settings for selecting the date range

https://github.com/HsuanXyz/ion2-calendar

Comment: it's ionic2 not ion2 :)